# How to run another model queries inside the sequelize hooks?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Below is my PurchaseOrder model defined in sequelize. I want to update the Supplier Model whenever there is an update to the PurchaseOrder. I thought of using the hooks to achieve this. But I couldn't able to access another model inside this model. I tried importing and all stuff, but no luck.  Is this the right way to use the hooks or what should I use to achieve the same? Any help or direction is much appreciated!

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const PurchaseOrder = sequelize.define("purchaseOrder", {
    totalAmount: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    paid: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    },
    paymentMode: {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('CASH', 'CHEQUE', 'BANK', 'CARD', 'NA')
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    hooks: {
      beforeUpdate: (order, options) => {
        // here I want to update the another model(Supplier).
        // But I couldn't able to access another model inside the hook
        Supplier.increment('balance'{
           where: { id: order.supplierId }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return PurchaseOrder;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my code I have a couple hooks that update other models (audit logging of changes for example). You need to make sure to pass along the `options.transaction` so that any changes are rolled back if there is an error later in the chain.

This example accesses another table keyed by `other_model`. When the hooks run the models should all already be registered with Sequelize.

```js
module.exports = function Order(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Order = sequelize.define(
      'order',
      { /* columns */ },
      {
        hooks: {
          beforeUpdate: async function(order, options) {
            // get the transaction, if it is set
            const { transaction } = options;

            // use sequelize.models and make sure to pass the 
            // transaction so it is rolled back if there is an error
            await sequelize.models.supplier.increment(balance, {
              where: { id: order.supplierId },
              transaction,
            });
          },
        },
      },
  });

  return Order;
}
```

Comment: In the case of sequelize-typescript library, something like this can be done:
`@BeforeDestroy
  static async deleteInstance(instance: Model, options: InstanceDestroyOptions) {
    await this.sequelize.transaction(async t => { ... })
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sequelize['Supplier']` because all models should be already registered in an Sequelize instance.

Nevertheless I suppose it's not a good idea to make modifications in a DB via other models in such hooks because in such cases you should take into account that all operations should be done in the same transaction i.e. should be executed as an atomic operation to avoid inconsistent state of data in a DB if some modifications fail.

Answer (score 0):

Not a relatable answer, but if anyone wants to try querying a model to another model using validate custom functions. You can define your model like `sequelize.models.ModelName` sequelize shouldn't be imported like require('sequelize') but it should use the sequelize parameter defined in module.exports of your current model.

```
await sequelize.models.ModelName.findAll()
```